# How to get apache to load custom page for 414 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-handling

Using htaccess, I've managed to make error pages show up beautifully on my site like such:

```
ErrorDocument errorcode /pathtopage
```

The included code works for every single error code I've tested except for **Error 414 Request URI too long**. It seems that Apache is completely ignoring the htaccess file in this case - is there a way to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument)

> Although most error messages can be overridden, there are certain circumstances where the internal messages are used regardless of the setting of ErrorDocument. In particular, if a malformed request is detected, normal request processing will be immediately halted and the internal error message returned. This is necessary to guard against security problems caused by bad requests.

It seems, that a "414 Request-URI Too Large" is considered severe enough, to ignore an appropriate `ErrorDocument 414` setting.

Answer (score 3):

Some error pages like 414 and 400 are only customizable in the server configuration. I don't know the reason for that, but if you have an own server that should be no problem.

Comment: Could you please give some pointers on where and how to customize it in the server config? And yes it's my own XAMPP server

Comment: I personally use my vhost file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\www\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`. Just dump it into your virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

For a "dirty hack" you can use something I use sometimes to my clients

```
ErrorDocument 414 '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/error/414"><script>document.location.href=/error/414;</script>'
```

It works fine in most situations. Also consider the alternative of RewriteCond, something like this.. Is only a pseudo example.. (for regex examples you must pay, just joking)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^({max leght of uri here})$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error/414
```

Hope to give you an idea, cya

Comment: Why would the "dirty hack" work when the direct-path-to-error-document does not? But you also have an _error_ in your "dirty hack"; the JS string needs to be enclosed in quotes. By redirecting the user in this way you are exposing the error document URL and ultimately returning a 200(OK) HTTP status code, unless you explicitly override this. But anyway, this "dirty hack" did not work for me - it still failed to override the servers default 414 error document.

Comment: Well, I tried it - doesn't work on my server. Still though the idea is very good.